# What level of decimal precision do QBO Invoice Items support?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We have a one-way sync which transfers our internal invoices to QBO.  The problem seems to be that once transferred to QBO the line items are rounded to the nearest cent and then summed, not summed and then rounded.

For example:

- Line item 1 = 0.75 x $0.50 = $0.375 (it will display as $0.38)
- Line item 2 = 0.75 x $0.50 = $0.375 (it will display as $0.38)
- Total = $0.375 + $0.375 = $0.75

If I try to do this in QBO, I will get:

- Line item 1 = 0.75 x $0.50 = $0.38
- Line item 2 = 0.75 x $0.50 = $0.38
- Total = $0.38 + $0.38 = $0.76

So the customer would have paid $0.75, but QBO thinks that the invoice is for $0.76 ultimately also resulting in the invoice appearing to be overdue.

I've tried entering items into QBO with greater precision, and it always rounds to the whole cent.

Is what we are doing not supported by QBO?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't relate to programming as defined in the [help]

Comment: How is it not "on-topic"?  It is a one-way sync and to achieve that it is using the API.  I think it is clearer explaining the issue then pasting the code and you interpreting what it is trying to do.